# Additive Reflection in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I loaded a mesh in three.js and loaded a grey texture with already baked in illuminations into a THREE.MeshBasicMaterial. Then I loaded a black and white Environment map with THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube, set reflectivity to 0.4 and mix it with THREE.MixOperation.

The problem is now, that the black parts of the environment map make the mesh darker, which is not what i want. I want only the reflection of the white parts, like in an additive blending or like a specular (but still from the environment map).

I can fake that by changing the black to a grey, but then the model becomes rather flat.

I tried to do it with some render passes like in this tutorial (http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-animated-selective-glow.html ), but then I get some anti aliasing gaps in some small geometry lines which i also have.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently not supported...

Do you mind posting it here as a feature request?
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues

Comment: Can you think of any workaround? Yes, gonna post it as a request.

Comment: While playing with the [editor](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/editor/) I found that setting `material.reflectivity` to -1 was kinda like additive, but the texture colors would need to be inverted I think.

Comment: I tested that and it actually looks pretty good with a reflectivity of -0.4 and an inverted environment map where the whitest point is a medium grey.